# R Copy one dataframe to another using data dictionary

Tags: dictionary, data-mapping, r-library

I'm looking create a function to copy the data from an incoming data file to a new data frame using a data dictionary. If I could schedule the mapping using a dataframe, it would be widely reusable with just the edit of a mapping table (a table would work too)

For exmaple, The incoming file would have these headers:

Number Name Desc Col S Mat Web Cost

and I want to map them to(This dataframe has additional Columns not in the incoming dataset that won't be matched):

SKU Title Description Img Color Size Material URL Price Shipping Weight Height Width...

Using the dataframe: (blanks have no incoming field to map)

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| Number | SKU |
| Name | Title |
| Desc | Description |
| Img | Img_URL |
| Col | Color |
| S | Size |
| Mat | Material |
| Web | URL |
| Cost | Price |
|  | Shipping |
|  | Weight |
|  | Height |
|  | Width |
|  | Length |
|  | Alternative_Images |
|  | Category |

Is there a library that does this kind of thing?  If not, other suggestions will be very helpful.